# How to get selected combobox items and text on button when I reopen the form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, button, combobox

I created a project in C# windows form application in visual studio 2010 and .net framework version 4.0.

In my project Main form contains another form which name is `Communication`.
Communication form has five combo box for COM Port settings and Connect button.
When I select Items from Combo box drop down list and click on connect button then text on button shows disconnect. Then I will close Communication form.Comport gets connected.

My main problem is that,  when I reopen form for disconnect communication. I want same Items in combo box and text on button shows Disconnect as before.

I don't know how to do this. Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Code for Communication form

```
 public partial class Connect : Form
{
    public bool Connect_Status = false;

    public Connect()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
        COM_List();

    }
   private void COM_List()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < CommPortManager.Instance.GetCommList().Count; i++)
        {
            cb_CommPort.Items.Add(CommPortManager.Instance.GetCommList()[i]);
        }
    }

  private void btn_Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CommPortManager.Instance.PortName = cb_CommPort.Text;
        CommPortManager.Instance.BaudRate = cb_BaudRate.Text;
        CommPortManager.Instance.Parity = cb_Parity.Text;
        CommPortManager.Instance.StopBits = cb_StopBits.Text;
        CommPortManager.Instance.DataBits = cb_DataBits.Text;

        if ((cb_CommPort.Text == "") || (cb_BaudRate.Text == "") || (cb_Parity.Text == "") || (cb_DataBits.Text == "") || (cb_StopBits.Text == ""))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select all communication settings and then Save", "TestCertificate", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            Connect_Status = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (CommPortManager.Instance.COM_Open() == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Could not open the COM port. Most likely it is already in use, has been removed, or is unavailable.", "TestCertificate", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                Connect_Status = false;
            }
            else
            {
                CommPortManager.Instance.COM_Close();
                Connect_Status = true;
                btn_Connect.Text = "Disconnect";

            }

        }
    }

 private void btn_Close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
 }
}
```

And Code for main form where this communication form open

```
 private void connectToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Connect connect = new Connect();
        connect.ShowDialog();
        if (connect.Connect_Status == true)
        {
            lb_Comm.Text = String.Format("Connected to '{0}'", connect.cb_CommPort.SelectedItem);
        }
        else
        {
            CommPortManager.Instance.COM_Close();
            lb_Comm.Text = "Not Connected";
        }
  }
```

Comment: You can take the help of 'Serialization'.

Comment: how About your Code?

Comment: Have a look at `Settings`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx

Comment: we need some code please and a better explanation. I can't imagine anything from this.

Comment: You need to save the settings before you close it, and load them when you open it.

Comment: @ BugFinder - I know that, but how to do that. how to save combo box settings and how to load it?

Comment: Look into persisting application data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a `Serializable` class in which you will be saving the indexes of combo boxes.

```
[Serializable]
class SaveComboSettings
{
    [OptionalField]
    public int cmb1SelectedIndex = 0;

    [OptionalField]
    public int cmb2SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

At the time of **closing** the **form**, You need to **serialize** the combo boxes's index in this class's object. Like -

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    //Assigning the current selected index of combobox to serialize class.
    SaveComboSettings f1 = new SaveComboSettings();
    f1.cmb1SelectedIndex = this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
    f1.cmb2SelectedIndex = this.comboBox2.SelectedIndex;

    //Serialize
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream fsout = new FileStream("ComboBoxSettings.binary", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
    try
    {
        using (fsout)
        {
            bf.Serialize(fsout, f1);                   
        }
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        //Some Exception occured
    }  
}
```

When form is loaded back/restart, You need to **deserialize** the settings and assign the combo box values back -

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DeserializeFormSettings();

}

public void DeserializeFormSettings()
{          
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
     FileStream fsin;

    if(File.Exists("ComboBoxSettings.binary"))
        fsin = new FileStream("ComboBoxSettings.binary", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
    else
        return;
    try
    {
        using (fsin)
        {
            SaveComboSettings f1 = (SaveComboSettings)bf.Deserialize(fsin);
            this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = f1.cmb1SelectedIndex;
            this.comboBox2.SelectedIndex = f1.cmb2SelectedIndex;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception Ex)
    {
        // "An error has occured";  
    }
}
```

This example is created with combo box only. You can use the same way for string on button also.

Comment: _You have to create a Serializable class_ No. This is just one of many ways to persist data.

Comment: @Arpit - As you said, I created Serialize class. But I did not get result.

Comment: @J.rao Not possible man. I have made this sample app and tested. Can you tell me what have you done exactly? Make sure you are serializing and de-serializing properly.

Comment: @Arpit -  i created serialize class for my 5 combobox. then created  Form1_FormClosing event and like above i created DeserializeFormSettings method for my five combo boxes in connect class.

Comment: @J.rao please keep break points and check if you are getting some exception.

Comment: @Arpit - Sry I forgot to use [Serializable] attribute in Serializable class. Now i am getting all settings back but new  problem here, when I close my main form or application and open it again. The communication form shows same saved settings. here i need blank combo boxes.

Comment: @J.rao To resolve that, When you are closing Main Form, delete the settings file programatically. So that when you open it again, the old settings not  available there.

Comment: private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
if(File.Exists("ComboBoxSettings.binary"))
{
    File.Delete("ComboBoxSettings.binary");
}
}

Comment: @Arpit - Thank you so much for your time. My issue is resolved.